# removeEventListener not working after an async call

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a form before it can be submitted. I'm following the pretty standard procedure of adding event listener to the form's `submit` event, canceling the default behavior, and then once everything has been validated, submitting the form through `submit()` method after removing the event listener. But for some reason, the event doesn't get removed and the page keeps on reloading. Here is my code:

```
// Prevent form submission on button click and validate form input fields first
cartForm.addEventListener('submit', validateInputFields);

function validateInputFields(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  validateName();
  validateRecipientPhone();
  validateCustomerPhone();
  validateAddress(submitForm);
}

function submitForm() {
  // remove validation event listener and submit form
  cartForm.removeEventListener('submit', validateInputFields);
  cartForm.submit();
}
```

Here `validateAddress` makes an async API call and takes some time to resolve therefore I passed `submitForm` as callback which can be triggered once `validateAddress` resolves. Does this have something to do with my form not getting submitted? Or am I making some other mistake? It's stuck in a loop no matter address gets validated or not.

The first three validation functions are only checking if fields are populated and have correct lengths.

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure validateInputFields is being called? Did you look at the console for errors?

Comment: I'd say there isn't enough code to see where the problem is. Can you provide a minimal reproducible code? You may try using `setTimeout` to mock a delay if needed.